# How can I search and show all records from my txt file?

Tags: python, search, text-files, record, show

I have tried some code before, but have not been successful. I mean when I search a file for a word, it just shows the first record of it and then turns to ask the back option. It completely ignores the second record. Moreover, when I search a wrong customer name, it won't print the statement like, "not existed". It was my practice, and might be a simple question but I am still a beginner. Hope anyone can help me on this. Thanks and I appreciate all help.

```
def search_payment():
  print("Please Enter Customer Username For Searching")
  search_username = input("Customer Username: ").upper()

  show_search_payment = open("customer_order_records.txt", "r")
  view_payment = show_search_payment.read()
  view_payment_by_line = view_payment.splitlines()
  show_search_payment.close()
  for line in view_payment_by_line:
      data = line.split(",")
      if search_username in data[0]:
          if search_username == data[0]:
              print("Searching.....")
              time.sleep(1)
              print("Done Searching!\n\n\n*----- "+ search_username + " CUSTOMERS ORDERS AND PAYMENT RECORDS -----*")
              print("*" * 45)
              print(" Username\t\t: ", data[0],"\n Date\t\t\t: ", data[1],"\n Ordered\t\t: ", data[2],"\n Total Quantity : ", data[3],"\n Total Amount\t: ", data[4],"\n Payment Method\t: ", data[5])
              print("*" * 45)
              while True:
                  back = input("\n(b) Back: ")
                  if back == "b" or back == "B":
                      search_order_payment()
                  else:
                      print("***Invalid Input! Please Try Again\n")
                      search_payment()
          else:
              print("Customer Username Does Not Exist! Please Try Again!\n")
              while True:
                  try_again = input("(b) Back  (c) Continue : ")
                  if try_again == "b" or try_again == "B":
                      search_order_payment()
                  elif try_again == "c" or try_again == "C":
                      search_payment()
                  else:
                      print("***Invalid Input! Please Try Again\n")
                      search_payment()
```

Here is my content inside the txt file:

```
ABC,Sun Jul 18 10:00:56 2021,NASI GORENG BIASA;RM6.00,1,RM6.00,CREDIT CARD,
WONG,Sun Jul 18 11:18:57 2021,ROTI CANAI KOSONG;RM1.60    TEH TARIK;RM2.60,3,RM5.80,TOUCH' N GO E-WALLET,
STANLEY,Mon Jul 19 11:05:18 2021,NASI GORENG SEAFOOD;RM10.50    NESCAFE NAI;RM2.80,2,RM13.30,CREDIT CARD,
WONG,Mon Jul 19 12:05:26 2021,ROTI CANAI PLANTA;RM3.90    TEH TARIK;RM2.60,3,RM10.40,TOUCH' N GO E-WALLET,
MAY,Mon Jul 19 12:20:51 2021,MURTABAK AYAM CHEESE;RM9.50    MILO;RM2.80,3,RM21.80,TOUCH' N GO E-WALLET,
```

Answer (score 1):

For your issue you should use `for-else` :
Here's the working code :

```
import time

def search_payment():
  print("Please Enter Customer Username For Searching")
  search_username = input("Customer Username: ").upper()

  show_search_payment = open("customer_order_records.txt", "r")
  view_payment = show_search_payment.read()
  view_payment_by_line = view_payment.splitlines()
  show_search_payment.close()
  for line in view_payment_by_line:
      data = line.split(",")
      if search_username==data[0]:
          print("Searching.....")
          time.sleep(1)
          print("Done Searching!\n\n\n*----- "+ search_username + " CUSTOMERS ORDERS AND PAYMENT RECORDS -----*")
          print("*" * 45)
          print(" Username\t\t: ", data[0],"\n Date\t\t\t: ", data[1],"\n Ordered\t\t: ", data[2],"\n Total Quantity : ", data[3],"\n Total Amount\t: ", data[4],"\n Payment Method\t: ", data[5])
          print("*" * 45)
          while True:
              back = input("\n(b) Back: ")
              if back == "b" or back == "B":
                  search_order_payment()
              else:
                  print("***Invalid Input! Please Try Again\n")
                  search_payment()
  else:
      print("Customer Username Does Not Exist! Please Try Again!\n")
      while True:
          try_again = input("(b) Back  (c) Continue : ")
          if try_again == "b" or try_again == "B":
              search_order_payment()
          elif try_again == "c" or try_again == "C":
              search_payment()
          else:
              print("***Invalid Input! Please Try Again\n")
              search_payment()
search_payment()
```

Your code is just searching for first element of the list, because there is `if-else`  at first and that will not giving program to check for second element of the list. So, you are facing that issue.

**Output(Tested with 2 existing value and 1 random value) :**

```
Please Enter Customer Username For Searching
Customer Username: ABC  <------------------------------ INPUT
Searching.....
Done Searching!


*----- ABC CUSTOMERS ORDERS AND PAYMENT RECORDS -----*
*********************************************
 Username               :  ABC
 Date                   :  Sun Jul 18 10:00:56 2021
 Ordered                :  NASI GORENG BIASA;RM6.00
 Total Quantity :  1
 Total Amount   :  RM6.00
 Payment Method :  CREDIT CARD
*********************************************

(b) Back: c
***Invalid Input! Please Try Again

Please Enter Customer Username For Searching
Customer Username: MAY  <---------------------------------- INPUT
Searching.....
Done Searching!


*----- MAY CUSTOMERS ORDERS AND PAYMENT RECORDS -----*
*********************************************
 Username               :  MAY
 Date                   :  Mon Jul 19 12:20:51 2021
 Ordered                :  MURTABAK AYAM CHEESE;RM9.50    MILO;RM2.80
 Total Quantity :  3
 Total Amount   :  RM21.80
 Payment Method :  TOUCH N GO E-WALLET
*********************************************

(b) Back: c
***Invalid Input! Please Try Again

Please Enter Customer Username For Searching
Customer Username: test  <----------------------------------- INPUT
Customer Username Does Not Exist! Please Try Again!

(b) Back  (c) Continue : c
Please Enter Customer Username For Searching
Customer Username:
```